# Postgresql searching with non-ascii character using ILIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have encountered interesting problem with character encodings in postgresql. The problem occurs with searching the table using ILIKE operator and using non-ascii characters ('ä','ö',..) in the search term. Seems that the search results differ depending on the encoding of the search term (as you can encode these non-ascii characters with many different way).

I know for a fact that I have in some tables (within 'character varying' columns) non-ascii characters with UTF-8 encoding and also with some other encoding (maybe latin-1, not sure). For example 'ä' character is present sometimes as correct UTF-8 representation 'C3 A4' but sometimes like this: '61 cc 88'. This is probably caused by the fact I imported some legacy data to the database that was not in UTF-8. This is not a problem most of time as they are presented in the Web application UI correctly anyway. Only the search is the issue. I.e. I cannot figure out a way to make the search find all the relevant entries in database as the results vary depending on the search term encoding (=basically problem is that search does not get the legacy data correctly as it has it's non-ascii characters mixed up).

Here are the facts on the application:

- Postgresql 11.5 (via Amazon RDS)
- Npgsql v4.1.2
- .net core 3
- react frontend
- database encoding UTF8, Collation en_US.UTF-8, Character type en_US.UTF-8

Any ideas what to do?

1. Write a batch job to convert all data to UTF-8 and update database & guard further data inserts somehow for using nothing but UTF-8?
2. Make postgresql ILIKE ignore the character encoding?

Edit: Found good page on unicode normalization in Postgresql: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/unicode-normalization-in-postgresql-13/